# Can I detect dead php code with SonarQube? If yes, how?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Well, simple question. Is there a way to detect dead code in php with Sonaqube? I looked for plugins to do this, but unfortunatly, I did not find anything.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no.

There are currently 8 [PHP rules related to unused code](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#languages=php%7Ctags=unused). However, the current state of PHP analyzer limits rules to running within a file, so there's not yet any ability to find classes in a project that are never used, for instance.

Comment: What a fast answer! Thank you. And too bad for me, I think rules will do the job. But again, thank you!